# ASP.NET 5 vNext - Getting a file stored in a different project (not the web project)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

How do i get the file stored in a folder inside a library project. (in ASP.NET 5 vNext)
after a request flow from the web project to a class in the data access project i need to parse a stored xml file into a model and send it back as a response.
I tried some solutions mentioned in : [here](http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/10/29/different-ways-of-getting-path/)
without any success.

Comment: You should mention that in a vNext project, project items do not have the `Copy to Output Directory` option.

Answer (score -2):

You should mark the propery `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`, and then access the file from your `bin` folder.

```
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin\\myFile.xml");
```

Comment: I Cant see a Copy to Output Directory option in the asp.net 5 vNext project viewing the properties of the file.

Comment: Same here, no "Copy to Output Directory". Have you managed to fix this?